# C++ application with neat codebase to learn from

Tags: c++, linux, posix, command-line-interface

I'm searching for an application written in C++ with a neat codebase, to learn from and maybe even contribute to it. A lot of applications written in C++ are either very large or doing some really advanced stuff, which is just the domain of C++.

A good candidate of size and shape would be something like [pacman](https://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/) and [libalpm](https://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/lib/libalpm) from Archlinux, but it is written in plain C, not C++. [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) is just far to big and [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) is looking awkward. [Gnote](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnote/tree/) looks to be a good starting point and I'm also using GNOME, but I wasn't sure about it because it offers a GUI. Which brings me back to *pacman*; I'm already using it myself and it doesn't distract with stuff like a GUI.

So I decided to look for something small and sane, which offers a CLI and which I can use myself. I opened the search of github with the terms *note + c++ + stars* and the result is [taskwarrior](https://github.com/taskwarrior/task). A brief look on the source of task(warrior) looks promising.

Do you know a neat project which written in C++?

Thanks

Comment: I think that this is one of those questions that while off-topic, would be a good thing to have on SO. It's not like new projects with clean codebases pop up left right and center, so the answers will be relevant for a while. I'd pitch in with a claim that Qt codebase is relatively clean, at least stuff outside of the core module. I'd say that the controls in the widgets module are not bad C++ :) Of course that is all C++0x, not C++11.

Comment: This question seems also not to fit on programmers.stackexchange.com, same paragraph there. But I think this could help others too, any idea?

Comment: @KubaOber C++0x == C++11

Comment: @zoska Not as implemented in various compilers. I've used it to mean "partial support of C++11". E.g. what you get with various versions of MSVC.